# How to use berkeley packet filter (BPF) on ubuntu

Tags: linux, networking, firewall, c

I did search but I did't find any BPF code to use on my computer, also there isn't any example code to use. My goal is to find low level functions to filter packets. I am working in C program language. I am using Ubuntu 12.04 with 3.2.0 kernel.

Comment: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_Packet_Filter) mentions [`bpfc` in `netsniff-ng`](http://netsniff-ng.org/) that might help here (seems to be packaged for Ubuntu).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may want to look into the [pcap](http://www.tcpdump.org/) library, from the folks who brought you tcpdump. Pcap is a cross-platform packet filtering library with support for BPF filters.

Comment: Yes, I am familiar with pcap but I need to go on lower level, I need to find how to use BPF. If pcap uses it there must be some library on machine which supports using BPF.

Comment: Article is old one, but in lack of more information on this field I'll mark answer accepted one.